# android - loaded image's height it bigger than actual image

Tags: android, imageview, size, pixel

I am loading an image from the web with a AsyncTask class and set it to a imageview in my code.

```
// loading of the image into the ImageView
new DownloadImageTask(MyImageView).execute("ImageURL");
```

the problem is, every time I load an image, the height of it is different, even though the width and height of the ImageView is warp_content.
I added sort of a border line with the Background and padding to see the actual height of it.
**Here is the xml**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivBigRecipeImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ingredientsTitle"
    android:background="#52D017"
    android:contentDescription="food"
    android:padding="1dp" />
```

**in here are the pics**

**sometimes this happens:**

[image]

**and sometimes this happens:**

[image]

**Any ideas? I want to just have it exactly the actual size of it**

**thanks!**

Comment: You could resize the ImageView at the end of the task

Comment: thanks for comment. its sounds okay but i need to get the actual width and height of the image dynamically and than set it

Answer (score 6):

Try to add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your `ImageView`, and it should work.